# PostgreSQL Base Types (Scalar Type)

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

I have a use case where a custom base type in a PostgreSQL database would be very beneficial for dealing with non-linear data.  The examples of this include defining using a input and output function to a C function.  In my case I would rather just define the inp and out functions using SQL and then using the "LIKE" to inherit everything else from the double precision.  Has anyone done this? is it even possible?

Possible example:

```
-- sample linear to logrithmic functions
CREATE FUNCTION to_linear(anyelement) RETURNS double precision
    LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$
SELECT CASE WHEN $1 > 0 THEN 30 / log($1::double precision) ELSE 0 END
$$;

create function to_log(anyelement) returns double precision
    language sql
as $$
select 10^($1::double precision/30.0);
$$;

-- create the base type
create type mylogdata
(

    INPUT = to_linear,
    OUTPUT = to_log,
    LIKE = double precision
) ;

-- sample use in a table definition 
CREATE TABLE test_table(
    mydata mylogdata
);
```

What I'm really after is a "sudo" or "partial" base-type to allow for a simple in-out conversions while allowing the existing functions (sum, average, etc...) to work on the inherited type (in this case, double precision); basically avoiding to write/rewrite functions in C.

Thoughts?  Ideas?  Comments?  Not possible? :)

Much Thanks!

---

> On a side note, if we had do go down the 'C' route, I think there could be an opportunity to create a more generic logarithmic scalar/base-type like the Char, Varchar, or Arbitrary Precision Number which could allow for the dynamic declaration of the log base and scale of the non-linear data.
>
> Something like this could a big win for the science community and those of us dealing with "wave" based data like sound, vibration, earth quakes, light, radiation, etc.  Here is a sample definition of the base:
>
> Logarithmic(base, scale)

```
-- Below my idea for use in a table definition 
-- Obviously the IN/OUT functions would have to be modified to use the base and scaling
-- as defined (  most likely in C ??  )

CREATE TABLE test_table
(
    mydata logarithmic(10, 30)
);
```

> If someone is interested in partnering in creating something like this, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write a data type with new type input and output functions, you have to write that in C. No doubt you can reuse a lot of functions from `double precision`.

But I would go the other way. Rather than having a type that looks like a number, but the known arithmetic operators behave weirdly, define a new set of operators on an existing data type. That can be done in SQL, and it feels more natural to me.

If you create an operator class for your new operators, you can also use them with indexes.

Comment: Interesting Idea...  so your thinking creating a new operator like  "+++" to add.  So how would you implement an aggregate like logsum()?

Also, one of main thoughts for a new type is to allow BI tools to natively interact with the underlying logarithmic data so sum or avg is the logrithmic sum or average.

Comment: If you need the normal operators, my idea won't help you. Implementing aggregates in SQL is easy, however.

Comment: - Can you take a look at this - why doesn't this work?  what did I miss? :)
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/a3e4b/1

Comment: The `SFUNC` has to modify the state with the new input, but your `log_add` uses only `$1` (the first argument). That looks wrong.